# What does javascript: before a method means?

Tags: javascript, syntax

What does javascript: before a method means?

I know that it is calling a function, but in what cases should we use it?

What is the difference between javascript:method() and method()?

Comment: Do you mean what is a method? If so a method is just a function, it's not something special that call a function.

Comment: @gillesc No. What is the difference between javascript:method() and method()?

Comment: A href attribute needs a protocol. And `javascript:` is just that. It tells the browser to handle everything after the `:` as JS. (same as `http:`, `ftp:`, ...)

Comment: it just tells the browser how to handle a url ,where there is some javascript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inline '**JavaScript:**' (e.g. *onclick="JavaScript:alert('test');"*) used to specify language of a following script snippet. Now it is deprecated and you should not use it. The [current HTML language specification](http://dev.w3.org/html5/html-author/) does not tell anything about this at all.